# JSON Serialization Failed when classifying images with Watson (iOS - Swift)

Tags: ibm-watson

I want to create an application that uses the camera and photo library to allow users to take photos and have them classified.
I have configured my Swift environment and have not been able to classify images even when including a URL from the internet. By the way, I'm using https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk

Here is a simple code:

```
import VisualRecognitionV3

let apiKey = "your-apikey-here"
let version = "YYYY-MM-DD" // use today's date for the most recent version
let visualRecognition = VisualRecognition(apiKey: apiKey, version: version)

let url = "http://blog.fashionsealhealthcare.com/sites/default/files/styles/blog_image_display/public/field/image/blogs/ibm_watson.png"
let success = { classifiedImages in
        print(classifiedImages) }
visualRecognition.classify(url: url, success: success)
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
JSON Serialization Failed. Could not parse the following data.
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "description": "Invalid output language specified.",
        "error_id": "parameter_error"
    },
    "images_processed": 0
}
```

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/blob/5beddbdcbe37e6c41fc221a6e7dc43ad4cbe3df6/Source/VisualRecognitionV3/Tests/VisualRecognitionTests.swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the Swift 3.0 version of the iOS SDK? Unfortunately, we're still in the process of migrating the SDK to Swift 3.0, and expect a number of bugs and issues along the way. For more information about the migration to Swift 3.0, you can follow [this issue](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/issues/376).

The iOS SDK works in Xcode 8 with Swift 2.3 as of v0.8.0. We recently became aware of a bug uploading .png images with Visual Recognition, but .jpg images seem to work just fine.

Comment: Hello,

It's been a while but I finally made it in downgrading my code to Swift 2.3. Unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same error:

Comment: Error Domain=com.ibm.watson.developer-cloud.VisualRecognitionV3 Code=400 "Invalid output language specified. -- Images Processed: 0" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid output language specified. -- Images Processed: 0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=parameter_error}

Comment: I'm even using another project as reference: https://github.com/olivanov/watson-insight

Comment: hi @VictorOliveiraAntonino - I see exactly the same ridiculous problem, "Invalid output language specified".  it must be taking the header when users are in non-english speaking countries ...